# How to change download location to external Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, lenovo, 22.04

So I have a Lenovo Thinkpad X131e Chromebook and I did a full UEFI firmware switch over to Ubuntu 22.04. After all the updates finished I only have 300.00 mb of storage space on my computer, I have a 2 Tb external Hard Drive so my Question is, is there a way to change my download location over to the External Hard drive?

Comment: What do you mean by "download location"?

Comment: If the ARM port also contains snaps then many apps including Firefox and Chromium need additional permissions to have access to external media (mounted under `/media` or `/mnt`).

Comment: The snap version of firefox on 22.04 did (does) have a bug which limits the downloads to the Downloads directory, not where you specify, even your Desktop will fail.  Upstream bug has been filed, so a fix should be in the pipeline. The failure ranges from the "Save" button greyed out, to silent failure when you can click the "Save".

Comment: I want all my downloads to download to the external hard drive not the computer is there a way to do that in terminal?

Comment: Install the .deb or Flatpak Firefox. Do not use the Snap version. That is for now the only way.